# Struggling with SKScene inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, sprite-kit

I have a subclass of SKScene called SPGamePlayScene. It does a bunch of stuff. I need to make another scene that does the same stuff as SPGamePlayScene, but a little more/little differently, so I thought I would subclass my SPGamePlayScene for this new scene, SPPracticeScene. however im having issues with my class level instantiation methods.

```
below is the method of SPGamePlayScene:

//SPGamePlayScene.m
+ (instancetype)sceneWithSize:(CGSize)size colored:(BOOL)colored {


    SPGamePlayScene *gamePlayScene = [SPGamePlayScene sceneWithSize:size];
    gamePlayScene.colored = colored;

    gamePlayScene.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];


    return gamePlayScene;
}
```

this works fine. However in my subclass of SKGamePlayScene, SPPracticeScene, I need to create an SPPracticeScene object using its super class's sceneWithSize colored method.

```
//SPPracticeScene.m which inherits from SPGamePlayScene
+ (instancetype)sceneWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    //this keeps giving me a SPGamePlayScene but I need it to be a SPPracticeScene 
    SPPracticeScene *practiceScene = (SPPracticeScene *)[self sceneWithSize:size colored:NO];


    //this line throws an exception because practiceHud is not a property of SPGamePlayScene
    practiceScene.practiceHud = [SPPracticeHud practiceHudAtPosition:CGPointMake(0, practiceScene.frame.size.height - 20) inClef:[SPGameState sharedInstance].clef inFrame:practiceScene.frame];
    [practiceScene addChild:practiceScene.practiceHud];


    return practiceScene;
}
```

I know that this returns an SPGamePlayScene so I tried casting it with no luck. The line that sets the practiceHud property causes a crash since SPGamePlayScene does not have that property (even though its supposed to be an SPPracticeScene. This is my first foray into custom subclasses/inheritance so im probably misunderstanding something about the way things need to be done/what types need to be returned etc. How can I make this work?

Comment: casting doesn't chnage the class of an object, you have to create an instance of your practice scene class

Comment: Yeah I think I just need to change the return type of my gameplay scene method to id instead of instancetype.

Comment: nope, that will still return an instance of the gameplay scene, you need to call [self sceneWithSize]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just overriding the initWithSize method and using an instance level initializer instead of a class level one. using an init method returning an id seemed to do the trick.

```
//SPGamePlayScene.m
 (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size colored:(BOOL)colored {

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        //some custom code here

    }
    return self;


}

//SPPracticeScene.m which inherits from SPGamePlayScene
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    //init it using the SPGamePlayScene custom initializer
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size colored:NO]) {
        //some custom code here


    }
    return self;

}
```

using the above code let me use the custom initializer for SPPracticeScenes super class, but add additional functionality to it that I needed, while making sure the object returned was of the correct type. I would love to know how I could have made it work with my class level initializers though.